# Pylint variable name doesn't conform to snake_case naming style

Tags: python, flask, pylint, pylintrc

I have multiple warnings from pylint like that:
'''Variable name "df" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style'''
As I could understand, it happens because of variable name length less than 3 symbols. however I would like to use variables like df, i, x etc.

So, I require to add several variable names to linting exceptions. I tried to add that names to good-names section of pylintrc file in my project directory, where manage.py is located:
*pylintrc:*
'''# Good variable names which should always be accepted, separated by a comma.
good-names=i,
j,
k,
ex,
Run,
df,
l,
l1,
l2,
l3'''
It didn't helped, I still received warnings about variable names style. I will highly appreciate if somebody could help with ideas.

Comment: Run from there with `pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc`. Probably it is not using your configuration file. Use whatever name your config file has. It looks you named yours pylintrc only (without dot)

Comment: I still can't understand, why my configuration file is not used... I renamed it to .pylintrc and run in terminal `pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc`. Nothing happened, terminal returned just a list of options. From documentation I see: Pylint searches for a configuration file in the following order and uses the first one it finds:

1. pylintrc in the current working directory
2. .pylintrc in the current working directory

Answer (score 25):

In the `.pylintrc` file, the `good-names=...` line should be prefaced by a `[BASIC]` keyword, i.e.:

```
[BASIC]

# Good variable names which should always be accepted, separated by a comma.
good-names=i, j, k, ex, Run, df, l, l1, l2, l3
```

Comment: And in VS Code: `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--good-names=x,y,z,i,j,n,f"],`. For what it's worth, `df` usually isn't a good variable name. It just tells that it probably is a pandas dataframe, but it doesn't tell at all what it contains.