# How to disable pylint error message for a specific file?

Tags: python, pylint

To receive an event in PyQT, you have to override the event-handler.

For example:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
```

In this case, pylint shows error **C0103 invalid-name**:

`Method name "resizeEvent" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style`

Pylint is right, but you cannot rename the method, else I will not get the event.

But I don't want to disable these pylint warning for the whole project. Is it possible to deactivate the warning locally? Or can I mark the method as @override?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66784120/13145954) answer your question?

Comment: I edited your question to include your error code and message name. add these details next time.

Answer (score 6):

I know you can disable a specific pylint message for an entire file.
So for error **C0103 (invlaid-name)** you could write at the top of your module:

```
# pylint: disable=invalid-name
```

the message will not show for this file.

Also you could disable a message for a specific line adding this syntax after this line, in your example it'd be:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
```

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829236/is-it-possible-to-ignore-one-single-specific-line-with-pylint#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20this%20feature%20has%20been,code%20or%20the%20symbolic%20names.)